Selenium send_keys gets error 405 Method Not Allowed
I am using Selenium in python to interact with a Whatsapp Web chat.
Locally everything works, but when I run the script on my server, the moment I need to type in the input box using Selenium's send_keys method, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error. I can't even make log outputs, because the return of this error overrides the return of the Except block.
Does anyone know how this can be resolved?
